# Box next to vector? What does it mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

What are these smaller boxes (not the big ones) supposed to mean next to a vector? 
[image: Box next to vector(s)]

Comment: I think it is supposed to stand in for the dot $\cdot$, but it did not render.

Comment: It is definitely the dot product. Not to mention the correct answer is the first one!

Comment: Alright, thank you very much. I had a feeling it was the dot product as that was the last thing I was taught in my calc 3 class. Thanks for confirming both of you.

Comment: @polfosol well, the correct answer should be the 3rd one (although we don't have a coordinate system or anything like it)